# Django: Periodic increment to all records in one field

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

Is there a more efficient way of incrementing all records of a field every hour besides running a task that loops through all records at set time intervals and individually updates all records?

For example, User_profile Model:

```
username | coins_bought | coins_free | coins_spent
Amadeus  | 0            | 0          | 0           <-- new user has 0 coins throughout
Ludwig   | 5            | 5          | 3
Elise    | 21           | 9          | 12          <-- old user with prior activity
```

1 hr later:

```
username | coins_bought | coins_free | coins_spent
Amadeus  | 0            | 0+1        | 0           
Ludwig   | 5            | 5+1        | 3
Elise    | 21           | 9+1        | 12
```

5 hr later:

```
username | coins_bought | coins_free | coins_spent
Amadeus  | 0            | 5          | 0           
Ludwig   | 5            | 10         | 3
Elise    | 21           | 14         | 12
```

In this example, users can buy coins or wait 1 hour until they all receive a free coin and can use in on the web-app. I can't make this feature client side, because it's not a mobile app, and caching is easy to corrupt.

Edit: I found the solution, if anyone else is stuck on this view this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)
You can run an update method on a queryset as such at set time interval:

```
Model.object.all().update(same_field=F('same_field')+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use an [update query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) which could be run from a scheduled task controlled by [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html). Celery's documentation is pretty good on this: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html